# Tagged services and dependency injection

Tags: symfony

In one of my services, I need to access all services that implement an interface, so I defined in services.yaml:

```
_instanceof:
    App\ReportPlaceholder\ReportPlaceholderInterface:
        tags: ['app.reportplaceholder']

report_helper:
    class: App\Service\ReportHelper
    public: true
    arguments:
        - $placeholders: !tagged app.reportplaceholder
```

and the corresponding class reads:

```
class ReportHelper
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;
    /**
     * @var ReportPlaceholderInterface[]
     */
    public $placeholders;
    /**
     * @var DataEvaluator
     */
    private $dataEvaluator;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                                DataEvaluator $dataEvaluator,
                                iterable $placeholders = [])
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->dataEvaluator = $dataEvaluator;

        dump([debug_backtrace(), $this->placeholders = $placeholders]);
    }
}
```

The weird thing is I am always getting **two** dump messages !!!

[image]

It seems like the ReportHelper service is created twice, once with and once without the tagged services.

Looking at the call stack I see that once (with empty iterator) it is `/var/www/symfony/var/cache/dev/ContainerAbdE4g8/getReportHelper2Service.php` (notice the "2"), and the second constructor call comes from an event dispatcher `/var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself, for those who are interested.
The error is connected with a misunderstandin I had of  symfony services and their names. 
So if you define a service with name like I did, eg

```
report_helper:
    class: App\Service\ReportHelper
    arguments:
        $xyz: '@other_service'
```

and then use standard dependency injection

```
class X {
    public function __construct(ReportHelper $rh){}
}
```

then these are two different services!!!
Because, there is implicitly via autowiring a **second default service** with name `App\Service\ReportHelper` instantiated, that is actually passed to `X` in the latter case!

So, by exchanging the `class:` in my service definition by the keyword `alias:`, only one instance is created with two ids.

```
report_helper:
    alias: App\Service\ReportHelper
    arguments:
        $xyz: '@other_service'
```